# Javascript - Create a currying function returning the list of parameters

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to create a currying function returning the list of parameters but I don't how to make it.
This is my code :

```js
const getParameters = arg => {
  const parameters = [];

  const innerFunction = arg => {
    parameters.push(arg);
    return innerFunction;
  };
  return innerFunction(arg);
};

getParameters(1)(2)(5); // => expected value [1,2,5]
getParameters(1)(2)(5)(20); // => expected value [1,2,5,20]
```

Comment: I'm not actually sure how you do this exactly as specified. What you could do is have `innerFunction` check whether `arg` is `undefined`, and if it is then return `parameters` rather than the function itself. That would then work if you did `getParameters(1)(2)(5)();`. But I'm not sure how to make it not require the final call (and not sure if it's even possible, although I'm not saying it definitely isn't).

Comment: what should `innerFunction` return? An array, or a function? It's either one or the other, it can't be both at the same time?

Comment: Yes, so I have to put a condition on the argument of the inner function. Like, If arg === undefined, return the array.

Comment: Why don't you just use `const createList = (...args) => args;` and invoke `createList(1,2,3,4)` instead? That way you wouldn't need or end the recursion either

Comment: @Esporia that's a fragile and error-prone construct you're building here. Why? What's the purpose of this construct?

Answer (score 1):

```js
const getParameters = a => b => c => [a, b, c];

console.log(getParameters(1)(2)(5));
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer but how can I make it with an unlimited number of parameters?

Comment: What would be the condition to stop? If the function can receive unlimited params, you need to have a way to specify that you don't want any more functions but the result.

Comment: Oh, ok I understand. So the only way to make it is to put a condition on the argument of the inner function .

Comment: You have a couple of options: 1) You can make the first arg that one that says how may args will be. 2) If you call the function without an arg `getParameters(1)(2)(5)()`, that means you want the result. But some how you need a way to say I want my result now.

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE: Support unlimited arguments.
PS: only limitation is when you need to end the call, you have pass last call as null or undefined or empty as shown below.

```js
const getParameters = a => {
  const parameters = [a];
  const innerFunction = b => {
    if (b) {
      parameters.push(b);
      return innerFunction;
    }
    return parameters;
  };
  return innerFunction;
};


console.log(getParameters(1)(2)(5)());
console.log(getParameters(1)(2)(5)(9)(20)(22)());
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer but how can I make it with an unlimited number of parameters?

Comment: @Esporia, updated the answer to support unlimited number of parameters, But there is caveat as mentioned and shown in above code. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Not very good solution, but... Try this one if you want to have a string in output.

```js
function getParameters(a) {

  let parameters = '[';
  parameters += `${a}`;

  function innerFunction(b) {
    parameters += `,${b}`;
    return innerFunction;
  }

  innerFunction.toString = function() {
    return `${parameters}]`;
  };

  return innerFunction;
}

console.log(getParameters(1)(3)(4)); //[1,3,4]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can use a final parameter(like "x") to signify end, you can use [`.bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind)

```js
const getParameters = function(...arg) {
  if (arg[arg.length - 1] !== 'x') {
    return getParameters.bind(null, ...arg);
  }
  arg.pop();
  return arg;
};
console.info(getParameters(1)(2)(5)('x'));
console.info(getParameters(1)(2)(5)(20)("x"))
```

Answer (score 0):

As we all know world of `JavaScript` is a magic world, and even this thing, like infinite currying is possible

```js
const nice = (...args) => {
  return Object.assign(
    nice.bind(0, ...args), 
    { valueOf: () => args.reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0) }
  )
}

console.log(+nice(1)()(2)) // ~> 3
console.log(+nice(1, 2)()(3)()()) // ~> 6
console.log(+nice()()()()()()(1)) // ~> 1
console.log(+nice()()()(2)()()()) // ~> 2

console.log(nice(2)()(1) + '') // ~> '3'

console.log(nice()(3)() == 3) // ~> true

console.log(nice()(3)() === 3) // ~> false
```

The trick is that adding unary + or using non-strict equality calls `valueOf` method right after all function calls, so we've got ourselves an infinite currying :)

And list currying to answer your question. It works because `'' +` forces toString method to be called:

```js
const nice = (...args) => {
  return Object.assign(
    nice.bind(0, ...args), 
    { toString: () => JSON.stringify(args) }
  )
}

console.log('' + nice(1,2)(3)(4)(5)(6,7)) // ~> [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
```

By the way, it's possible to make this infinite currying even more legit, because it can take any type and any amount of parameters which's really cool.

<3